# How to access the second last element of a string

Tags: c++, string

this is a function that checks if a person is a man or a woman by checking the second

last element of his social security number. If the number is even then the person is a

woman. If odd then a men. The code is working in a strange way. Sometimes it does the job

and sometimes not. this is the code:

```
char check_gender(string person_nummer){
    int check_digit = (person_nummer.back() - 1) - '0'; 
    char gender; 
    if(check_digit % 2 == 0){
        gender = 'K';     // K for a women(kvinna in swedish)
    }
    else{
        gender = 'M';     // M for man
    }
    return gender;
}
```

```
int main(){
  string number; 
  cout << "enter number" << endl; 
  cin >> number; 
  cout << check_gender(number) << endl; 
  return 0; 
}
```

input1: 8602024898

output1: M     // correct output

input2: 8510309159

output1: K     // wrong output

input3: 7102022980

output M       // wrong output

input4: 4906147410

output M       // correct output

weird!

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This returns the last character in the string:

```
person_nummer.back()
```

you then subtract `1` from it. That means, if the last character is `'9'`, you now have `'8'`.

To get the second last character, you need;

```cpp
person_nummer[person_nummer.size() - 2]
```

This will give the correct output for your example numbers:
[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/vqc8hEWon)

Getting the second last character using iterators:

```
*std::prev(person_nummer.cend(), 2)
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/hvPd8hceq)

or reverse iterators:

```
*std::next(person_nummer.rbegin())
```

> The code is working in a strange way. Sometimes it does the job and sometimes not.

You will get a number by doing `person_nummer.back() - 1` but it's a 50/50 chance that it'll be correct for the entered `person_number`. The last digit is a check digit and has nothing to do with the gender but you were using it to determine gender.

Comment: `*(person_nummer.cend() - 2) - '0'` should work fine as well if OP wants iterator semantic instead

Comment: @TheDreamsWind Yes, or `*std::prev(person_nummer.cend(), 2) - '0'`.

Comment: @TheDreamsWind now the output is 'k' for all input so it's not working at all

Comment: @sam I added a demo where you can see that it does the correct thing.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I can see you wrote [] instead of (). when I change it to []  I get an error: expected ',' or ']' in lambda capture list. I even tried with person_number.cend() and it's still giving k for all inputs

Comment: @sam If you get that you must have done something wrong. If you just replace `person_nummer.back() - 1` with `person_nummer[person_nummer.size() - 2]` it will work fine. Just check the demo.

Comment: Also: `*std::next(person_nummer.rbegin())`.

Comment: @bitmask Indeed. Endless possibilities :-) Added that too.

Comment: @TedLyngmo working now sir thank you. But why did my code work in some cases and didn't work in others

Comment: @sam Great! You're welcome! I added an explanation for why you got the correct answer sometimes and sometimes not.

Comment: @TedLyngmo yeah I can see it now. thanks again

Comment: Random-access iterators support `operator[]`: I would prefer `person_nummer.cend()[-2]` or `person_nummer.crbegin()[1]`.